# Converting Lat Lng to Address displays null in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart, geolocation, geocoding

The function displays the location Location NULL. I am getting the current location in superinit state and **want to display the address from the placemark as text** in the size box widget.

The function I have created to convert latitude and longitude to address **getAdd()** is also initialized in the initial state but when I call placemark in the text widget it displays null.
I have entered dummy values as well and tried printing in debug console which says.

```
E/flutter (29935): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(IO_ERROR, A network error occurred trying to lookup the supplied coordinates (*******************, *******************)., null, null)
E/flutter (29935): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope
package:flutter/…/services/message_codecs.dart:597
E/flutter (29935): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:158
E/flutter (29935): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29935): #2      MethodChannelGeocoding.placemarkFromCoordinates
package:geocoding_platform_interface/…/implementations/method_channel_geocoding.dart:56
E/flutter (29935): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29935): #3      _MapState.getAdd
package:donation_yoga/screens/maps.dart:32
E/flutter (29935): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29935):
```

The Map class is the following

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'AddData.dart';

class Map extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MapState();
}

class _MapState extends State<Map> {
  Position curLoc;
  bool mapToggle = false;
  GoogleMapController mapController;
  List<Placemark> placemarks;

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best)
        .then((curL) => {
              setState(() {
                curLoc = curL;
                mapToggle = true;
              }),
            });
    getAdd();
  }

  getAdd() async {
    placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(52.2165157, 6.9437819);
    print(placemarks);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          myLayoutWidget(),
          _createForm(context),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 200.0,
              height: 100.0,
              child: Card(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    "Location $placemarks",
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ), //Text
                ), //Center
              ), //Card
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget myLayoutWidget() {
    return Container(
        child: mapToggle
            ? GoogleMap(
                initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: LatLng(curLoc.latitude, curLoc.longitude),
                    zoom: 15.0),
                myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
              )
            : Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Getting Location Please Wait.....',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                ),
              ));
  }

  Widget _createForm(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        child: const Icon(Icons.create),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddData()),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you find the solution to this bug?

Comment: yes, I was able to do it